# "derivative for aten::linear_backward is not implemented" when calling backward() on mps in torch

Tags: pytorch, gpu, loss-function, generative-adversarial-network, discriminator

I'm working on a GAN to generate sounds. I copied most of the code from the wavegan-pytorch github. I'm working on a MacBook with M2 core, so I wanted to shift the processing from cpu to gpu with mps. But when I call torch.Tensor.backward() on my loss I get an Error, that linear_backward is not implemented. I'm still pretty new to programming, is there a simple mistake, that I overlook, or is it just not possible to run the code on gpu? Here's my code:

```
real_signal = next(self.train_loader)

# need to add mixed signal and flag
noise = sample_noise(batch_size * generator_batch_size_factor)
generated = self.generator(noise)
#############################
# Calculating discriminator loss and updating discriminator
#############################
self.apply_zero_grad()
disc_cost, disc_wd = self.calculate_discriminator_loss(
    real_signal.data, generated.data
)
assert not (torch.isnan(disc_cost))
disc_cost.backward()
self.optimizer_d.step()
```

would be very glad for help. Let me know, if you need more info, I'm sorry in advance, if there's a simple solution, that I don't get, because I'm new to this.

Here is the code for the calculate_discriminator_loss() function:

```
def calculate_discriminator_loss(self, real, generated):
    disc_out_gen = self.discriminator(generated)
    disc_out_real = self.discriminator(real)

    alpha = torch.FloatTensor(batch_size * 2, 1, 1).uniform_(0, 1).to(device)
    alpha = alpha.expand(batch_size * 2, real.size(1), real.size(2))

    interpolated = (1 - alpha) * real.data + (alpha) * generated.data[:batch_size * 2]
    interpolated = Variable(interpolated, requires_grad=True)

    # calculate probability of interpolated examples
    prob_interpolated = self.discriminator(interpolated)
    grad_inputs = interpolated
    ones = torch.ones(prob_interpolated.size()).to(device)
    gradients = grad(
        outputs=prob_interpolated,
        inputs=grad_inputs,
        grad_outputs=ones,
        create_graph=True,
        retain_graph=True,
        only_inputs=True,
    )[0]
    # calculate gradient penalty
    grad_penalty = (
        p_coeff
        * ((gradients.view(gradients.size(0), -1).norm(2, dim=1) - 1) ** 2).mean()
    )
    assert not (torch.isnan(grad_penalty))
    assert not (torch.isnan(disc_out_gen.mean()))
    assert not (torch.isnan(disc_out_real.mean()))
    cost_wd = disc_out_gen.mean() - disc_out_real.mean()
    cost = cost_wd + grad_penalty
    return cost, cost_wd
```

Comment: Its difficult to see exactly what causes the error from this small code sample. A more extensive code example might help. Particularly what 'self.calculate_discriminator_loss) returns. Most likely, `disc_cost` is not a Tensor. To ensure its a tensor, check whether `isinstance(disc_cost, Tensor) == True`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. The disc_cost is a Tensor and checking it with isinstance() returns True. I also edited the post and added the code for the discriminator loss calculation function. Thanks in advance for checking for mistakes.

Comment: Seems that there is a similar issue in pytorch. Perhaps they simply did not implement the derivative yet for Mac's (see issue for it on pytorch: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/92206)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing you are implementing the discriminator loss calculation from a WGAN-GP, I thought I'd work out what was going wrong and improve what you have.

First, you were doing absolutely great, with some slight flaws here and there. The problem is indeed in the calculate_discriminator_loss function. Things to improve:

1. `Variable` is deprecated in the most recent version of Pytorch. I'd recommend not to use it because it is unsupported.
2. You can index the `generated` and `real` tensors without accessing the `data` attribute, like so: `generated[:batch_size * 2]
3. I am not sure what you are trying to do with the `batch_size * 2`. Is the generated batch bigger than the real batch of data? I would advise to keep them the same size.
4. PyTorch has an `expand_as` function which is really useful here (instead of `expand` and then to define the size of some tensor).
5. When computing the gradients, you do not need `retain_graph=True` as you don't compute gradients twice.
6. When computing gradients, you do not need `only_inputs=True`. It is deprecated, and the default setting is True.
7. `p_coeff` and `device` are not variables defined in the function. Make sure to define them in the class, and then access them through `self.p_coeff` and `self.device`.

The following works when I run it:

```py
def calculate_discriminator_loss(self, real, generated):
    assert real.shape == generated.shape
    disc_out_gen = self.discriminator(generated)
    disc_out_real = self.discriminator(real)

    alpha = torch.rand(self.batch_size, 1).to(self.device)
    alpha = alpha.expand_as(real)

    interpolated = (1 - alpha) * real + alpha * generated

    # calculate probability of interpolated examples
    prob_interpolated = self.discriminator(interpolated)
    ones = torch.ones(prob_interpolated.size()).to(self.device)
    gradients = grad(
        outputs=prob_interpolated,
        inputs=interpolated,
        grad_outputs=ones,
        create_graph=True)[0]

    # calculate gradient penalty
    grad_penalty = (
        torch.mean((gradients.view(gradients.size(0), -1).norm(2, dim=1) - 1) ** 2)
    )

    cost_wd = disc_out_gen.mean() - disc_out_real.mean()
    cost = cost_wd + grad_penalty
    return cost, cost_wd
```

Cleaned up your code a bit as well to be more readable and removed the asserts.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Robin for your help. The code looks much cleaner now. The `batch_size * 2` is indeed weird, but it's based on a conversion I perform on my data. So I choose a small batch size, but then have to double it later. So I checked that all Tensors still have the same size. Unfortunately the error still pops up and I think it has to do, with working on an mps device. I tried to work in a conda env and set the environment variable `PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK=1` but that didn't work either.

Comment: what version of pytorch are you running on?

Comment: I'm running version 1.13.0

Comment: if it is an MPS error, you should try to run it on your cpu (just do device='cpu'). If it is an mps error, then you code should work just fine on cpu.

Comment: the code does run smoothly on cpu, the error only shows up, when I try to run it on gpu with the mps device.